# How did IIS get address of my service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7

This is my first time with WCF web service and also with IIS. The way I am hosting my WCF web service is through a .svc file. I have added a website in my IIS and pointed it to the folder that contains .svc file.

Now, while configuring IIS it did ask me to enter Host name to which I entered localhost **assuming** that this would be the address of my website.

However, that did not turn out to be the case. I am browsing to localhost and getting 404. Now, when I ran my service which has WCF service website project(the project which contains .svc file) it did populate the WCF client window which shows following address as my service address :

http://localhost:31893/Employee.svc. I am adding my web.config file just for the reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EmployeeServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="16384" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="PL.HR.Employees.WebService.HREmployeeWebService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EmployeeServiceBinding" name="StandardEndpoint" contract="PL.HR.Employees.WebService.IHREmployeeWebService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now, I though that this must be the Visual Studion Dev environment address that VS is generating at the run time. But NO this was the address to my WebHost that I added into IIS. This raised couple of questions in my mind:

1. How did Visual Studio know about my IIS mapping?
2. What is this **31893** generated by VS/IIS? I don't remember specifying anything like this when configuring the IIS website?
3. Does me specifying **Host name= localhost** change anything in final output of URL generated by visual studio?
4. Do I have any control over how final URL of my service is going to look like? What if I want it to be www.xyz.com?

Comment: Can you post an example of the code?  Additionally are you 100% sure that the one you added is actually associated with 31893.  This is done via Bindings and you would have had to add the extra port explicitly

Comment: For question number 4 :  localhost is nothing but IP Address 127.0.0.1. so you can name the URL as per your need for ex: www.xyz.com by mentioning it in the hosts file present under `C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Just add this line in your hosts file `127.0.0.1      www.xyz.com`

Comment: It sounds to me like Visual Studio is using IIS Express.  If you look in the project properties under web, you can tell it to use Local IIS (IIS Express is the default, I believe).  It will be local host, and the port number is dynamic.

Comment: I agree with Tim and the IIS Express best-guess.

Comment: Well, I have mapped this .svc to IIS so without having to run the visual studio, I can get to this location.

Comment: I updated the question with the config file if that helps :)

Comment: @Tim: Your assumption is right. I found this file called application.Config which has configured `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:31893:localhost" />` and that is bound to EmployeeService. Also, this file is located in IISExpress folder. However, now sure how IISExpress got invovlved in whole process and how IIS synced with it.

Answer (score 0):

That number at the end of localhost is the port number that IIS is listening on. If you want a domain, you can edit your hosts file at %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

Web.config holds settings in IIS. So if you change something in IIS, the Web.config is modified (and vice-versa), which causes a recycle of the AppPool.

Editing the bindings for your site will allow you to set a specific port number, but you have to change the debugging options in VS so it knows what is hosting the code you're debugging.

Pardon my lack of formatting, I'm using the stack exchange app on my lunch break.